# Short story: covert agent on planet "Iatria"(?), gadgets disguised as buttons on his clothes

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story took place on a planet named something like Iatria.  The main character is some sort of covert exploration agent from off-planet, trying to observe the locals without being detected as such.  He meets a young woman who works in a record shop, who shows him around.  Late in the story, they are captured by local officials, and he uses buttons on his clothes to save himself & her.  One is apparently a communicator with his ship, and another some sort of compact grenade.

I'm pretty sure it was a short story in an anthology book.

Comment: Vague feeling I might have read this, but I can't quite place it. Do you have anymore to give?

Comment: I think I recall a scene that takes place in a public park, where the couple hide by making out, an activity not at all frowned on there.  

I probably read it before 1984.  

Beyond that, I really can't remember much.

Comment: Is the planet very cold?

Comment: Not that I recall, and that would make making out in the park unlikely. :)

Comment: What I was thinking of: "Poor Planet" by J. T. McIntosh. In that story, the planet's name is Solitaire. The main character is a spy sent to find out why it has remained a poor, low-population and low-tech planet for as long as it has, when by theory it should have prospered. He does have special buttons, one of which communicates with his ship. He meets a girl in a music shop (looking for an old version of an opera), and they are both captured by the local security force - but escape, due to buttons. The planet is cold but the park is in a heated dome, and there is a scene there. Close at all?

Comment: Also, coincidentally, in the collection in which I found it, it is immediately followed by "Shamar's War" by Kris Neville. That story features a planet named Itra with the natives called Itraians, in which the main character is also an undercover offworlder (sent to foment a revolution). It seems like a reasonable mistake of memory to blend them a bit if you read them one after the other. (The collection is _Seven Trips Through Time and Space_ edited by Groff Conklin.)

Comment: Perfect!  That's exactly the book!

I had thought I read it from the public library, but it turns out it was in _my_ library all along.  I shall re-read it after the book I'm on now.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: Great! It seemed like a long shot, but I'm glad to have been a help. I've combined the comments above as a single answer. Please accept it when you get a chance, so your question will be marked as correctly answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you were looking for a blend of two stories in the same collection: "Poor Planet" by J. T. McIntosh and "Shamar's War" by Kris Neville. Both can be found one after another in the collection *Seven Trips Through Time and Space*, edited by Groff Conklin.

In "Poor Planet," the planet's name is Solitaire. The main character is a spy sent to find out why it has remained a poor, low-population and low-tech planet for as long as it has, when by theory it should have prospered. He does have special buttons, one of which communicates with his ship. He meets a girl in a music shop (looking for an old version of an opera), and they are both captured by the local security force - but escape, due to buttons. The planet is cold but the park is in a heated dome, and there is a significant scene there.

It is immediately followed by "Shamar's War." That story features a planet named Itra with the natives called Itraians, in which the main character is also an undercover offworlder (sent to foment a revolution). It seems like a reasonable mistake of memory to blend them a bit if you read them one after the other.

Comment: It's funny what 30 years will do to memory. :)